# Android Studio not showing any log on Run Tab

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

One week ago the run tab stopped showing logs. Usually it was showing errors, general logs, info of the application running, etc, but now it only shows this:
[Run Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3fEf.png)

After some time, android studio stops tracking the app that was launched: [AS Stops tracking the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvsKe.png)

And if I checked the logcat tab, it says there are no debuggable processes: [No debuggable processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV7Ta.png), even though the app in the emulator is still running.

I don't know if maybe it is some sort of setup that I changed unintentionally or if it is indeed a bug generated with the latest version of android studio for linux (ubuntu 20.04), what I do know is that I would like to receive feedback on this, since that run tab is the first thing that provides quick info about the app and it was working nicely. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Delete the '.idea' folder inside your project and run again.

Answer (score -2):

Well, in order to solve the issue I had to reinstall all the components of AS, incluing SDKs and so forth, worked perfectly after that

Comment: You can also use wired debugging